# How can I select files from list on Mac-OS

Tags: macos, terminal

I've got a bunch of .cr2 and .jpg files with exact same names. ".cr2" is a file format for digital negative, every .jpg is a converted to 8bit version of cr2-photo. Every photographer with canon camera get this kind of structure: take one picture - get one .cr2 version and one .jpg version. Cr2-s weights a lot, thats why I send jpegs to my clients to filter. After they send back best hundred photos from thousands, I must pick cr2 versions of this photos, one by one. There is gotta be a better way. In windows I find a way to select this files in totalcommander through copy selection to buffer - modifing(replace in text editor every ".jpg" to ".cr2") and then restore selection from buffer. This problem is seemed dumn, but I can't find an answer to mac, it took forever to select this files one by one and all photographers I know doing the same, which is driving me crazy.

Comment: I can help you with this easily but need a better explanation from you first. Do the clients send you back a list of files they like, or the actual images? What do you want to do when you have a list of the corresponding `.cr2` files - do you want to copy them somewhere? Or delete the ones that are not on the list? Or want?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Clients send me back the actual images they liked. I want to copy corresponded cr2 files to a new folder.

Comment: Ok, nearly there... where can I find the original `.CR2` images? And where do you want them copied to? What about the mechanics of it - let's say you save the original files the client chooses back in some specific, named folder, e.g. Desktop/accepted so my script looks in Desktop/accepted and finds all the JPEGs in there, then it goes to <?WHERE?> and finds the corresponding `CR2` files and places them in there with the selected JPEGs maybe? Or should it work a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script that should do what you want simply by double-clicking it. First you need to edit the first 2 lines to tell it 1) where the CR2 files can be found and 2) where the JPEGs are that the client has accepted.

Initially, I am assuming the CR2 files are somewhere under your login/home directory and that the JPEGs accepted by the client are on your Desktop in a folder called `accepted`. Edit lines 3 and 4 to reflect the actual situation, then save the following script on your Desktop as `GetCR2s.command`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# You can edit the next two lines to match your setup
CR2LOCATION="$HOME"
ACCEPTEDLOC="$HOME/Desktop/accepted"

shopt -s nocasematch    # Match JPG and jpg and CR2 and cr2 regardless of case
shopt -s nullglob       # Don't die if there are no files

# Tell user what is going on...
echo Locating CR2s in $CR2LOCATION, to match accepted files in $ACCEPTEDLOC...

# Go where the JPEGs are, or give up
cd "$ACCEPTEDLOC" 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo ERROR: Unable to change directory to $ACCEPTEDLOC; exit 1; fi

# Consider all JPEGs in this directory
for f in *.jpg; do
   cr2="${f%%jpg}cr2"   # Replace "jpg" extension with "cr2"
   echo Processing \"$f\", looking for \"$cr2\"...
   find "$CR2LOCATION" -iname "$cr2" -not -path "$ACCEPTEDLOC" -exec cp "{}" . \; 2> /dev/null
done
```

Then, start the Terminal application, and do the following just one time before use in order to make the script executable:

```
cd Desktop
chmod +x GetCR2s.command
```

Now you should be able to save the images your client has accepted (by clicking `Save Attachments` in your Email program) into the `Desktop/accepted` folder, then simply double-click on the script `GetCR2s.command` on your Desktop and it will gather all the matching CR2 files into that folder for you.